# Ipthnc being abusive, gaming rep

Tags: discussion, reputation, abuse

[Ipthnc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231677/lpthnc) has a stated goal of [rep-whoring to 1,000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995815/what-is-the-best-way-to-gain-high-reputation-on-so-closed), seemingly by [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025126/is-there-a-brainfuck-implementation-for-net-closed) means possible.  To this end, he has asked several bad questions and given answers it was clear weren't researched (though after a downvote and a comment on why, he will delete them).  I have seen two questions of his (one on SO, the other the Harvar/unfair from meta) deleted, and many more have been closed, with a handful I've also flagged as spam (which I believe they really were).

Veiled insults like *"Hey Dragan, where did you learn to type in English so well? http://ebaumsworld.com/video/watch/80821196"* (in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024024/kwargs-sent-over-pyamf-channel/2024251#2024251)) or *"What kind of name is Dragan Chupacbrovic? Welcome aboard! You shall be known as Chewy."* aren't unusual either.

However, he has also asked a handful of [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995734/how-are-exceptions-implemented-under-the-hood) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009119/how-to-combine-two-generators-in-a-non-trivial-way) (though that second I wonder if it was spammed from a tutorial) and provided a few good answers (possibly by accident?), and contrary to what I'm sure he believes, I have upvoted him (just rarely).

We both seem to be interested in the same topics, and sometimes [we](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025126/is-there-a-brainfuck-implementation-for-net-closed) [clash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024024/kwargs-sent-over-pyamf-channel/2024251#2024251) in comments.

Should I back down, or continue?  Are the moderators aware of this issue?  Or would you just tell me to go fsck myself?

Comment: Just take off the other sock.

Comment: Roger, I like you for the most part. Don't take life too seriously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downvote and flag as appropriate.

Don't let yourself get worked up about some random stranger trying to earn worthless "points" on a website.

Comment: That's the other hand.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get worked up as such, but I spend my time to make SO better (blah blah, in various ways) and dealing with such things is an annoying distraction---and I can't be the only one.

Comment: @Roger: it gets to quite a number of passionate SO users. I've somehow gotten over it and moved on... haha

Comment: Points aren't worthless given that they could be translated into a job, or at least a foot in the door to an interview.

Comment: @Jason: Points are worthless.

Answer (score 1):

I would say continue to 'clash' if you feel rightly so. Just don't get personal over it.

To me and most guys here, it's too tiring to blacklist/target specific users for their ill-mannered (if indeed) behavior.

Do what you want to do as a contributor to this community. If anyone (or Ipthnc himself) posted something good, upvote them. If you do not feel right, reason it out. Fair and square and you will sleep well at night.

My 2 cents :P

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of another user's stated intentions, I think we should encourage people to participate if they're being constructive (or even just *mostly* constructive on average). Individual transgressions (bad questions/answers) can be dealt with specifically without tarring the user.

Comment: Yes, I've never brought up past transgressions on constructive posts, but I won't hesitate on non-constructive posts and spam.  For example, edit history (revisions 2 and 3) at http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2025308/list, with no mention of past transgressions, since I can't say the question isn't constructive, even though I know he's primarily trying to get rep.